# SiriKit (iOS 12) Custom Intent Handler Not Being Called

Tags: ios12, sirikit

I have setup a custom intent and it all seems to be working fine except that the handler is not being called. Siri responds as if everything was successful but I don't see anything in the console output and none of my breakpoints are triggering... Here is the handler...

```
@implementation IntentHandler  

- (id)handlerForIntent:(INIntent *)intent  
{  
    // This is the default implementation.  If you want different objects to handle different intents,  
    // you can override this and return the handler you want for that particular intent.  

  NSLog(@"In handlerForIntent.");  

  if ([intent isKindOfClass:[TriggerSceneIntent class]])  
  {  
       return [SceneIntentsHandler sharedInstance];  
  }  

    return self;  
}  

@end
```

I have breakpoints at the if statement and both return statements. None of them are being hit. I also never see "In handlerForIntent" in the console log in xCode.

I'm guessing this is something fairly simple that I missed but I'm not seeing it. Welcome any suggestions?

Comment: Anyone solved this?

Comment: @birdcage still an issue. It seems like the project or the intents file can get out of whack. The other project I was working on was working just fine.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a same problem - handler wasn't called.

Finally I've found out, that although the project supports iOS 11.4, it initially set IntentExtension target to iOS 13. And my device, which I use for testing, has 12.4.

So my advice: check your deployment target for each target.

Comment: This fixed it for me !